# How do I latch, a cell in Excel and make it remain that way

Tags: excel, monitor

I want to constantly monitor A1 and if it ever becomes a "1", B1 should become "True" and remain that way.

Duplicating the value will send it right back when A1 becomes a 0 again.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Based on you explaination.

```
=if (a1=1,"True","")
```

Comment: That won't work for me.
Once A1 goes back to 0 the cell will go blank.  
I want it to remember that A1 was "at one point" a 1 and stay "True"